# WCF Data Services - The context is already tracking a different entity with the same resource Uri

Tags: wcf-data-services

A bit of context on how I am using wcf data Services, my production environment work in a DMZ schema so I am using a MVC projects that Connects to the the DMZ data server using  wcf data Services which in this case run the services and the mvc runs the client.

I am getting an errors on wcf data Services when trying to update an entity using  proxy.UpdateObject(entity) then proxy.SaveChanges() throws this error 'The context is not currently tracking the entity'

That issue is fixed when I do attach the entity to the context like that proxy.AttachTo("Entity", entity) and work the first time.

However updating the entity again throws another error 'The context is already tracking a different entity with the same resource Uri' for this error I have tried but with not luck Detach or TryGetEntity but nothing work then I tried to use proxy.GetEntityDescriptor(enity) but always return null.